Laravel BeyondCo Websocket - SSL Certificate and Proxy
I have been trying for days to configure a Laravel project using the Laravel WebSocket library. My app works fine when I test it locally, but as soon as I deploy it on a production machine running Linux inside a container and configure its DNS (e.g., https://test.websocket.com), the WebSocket stops working. Currently, the project is inside a Docker container, and I'm using supervisord to run php artisan serve and php artisan websocket:serve. The machine hosting the project also contains a Swag container, which routes the requests. Inside the Swag configuration file located at swag/config/nginx/proxy-conf/mywebsite.conf, I have this configuration.
Here my proxy conf file
map $http_upgrade $type{
 default "web";
 websocket "ws";
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name myTest.com;


    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        try_files /nonexistent @$type;
    }
    location @web {

        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app dockerAPP; 
        set $upstream_port 8001;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
    }


    location @ws {

        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:6001;
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
        proxy_redirectoff;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

}

bootstrap.j
import axios from 'axios';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

// Inizializzazione di Pusher
window.Pusher = Pusher;

// Inizializzazione di Echo
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key', // Verifica che la chiave corrisponda alla tua configurazione Pusher
    cluster: 'mt1',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    forceTLS: true,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
   
    disableStats: true,
    // encrypted: false,
    // cluster: 'mt1',
    // enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});

console.log("WebSocket connecting to " + window.location.hostname);

BroadCasting.php
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY', 'your-pusher-key'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET', 'myTest'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID', 'myTest'),
            'options' => [
                // 'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'encrypted' => true,
                'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
                'debug' => true,
                'scheme' => 'https',//env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
                'useTLS' => true, //env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

For now i also try to generate some ssl certifcate from cloudfare, and put this certificate in:
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/var/www/Abbodash/ssl/test.com.cert"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/var/www/Abbodash/ssl/test.com.priv.cert"


I also try to setup de tunnelconfig.yml file inside the swag container like this
- hostname: myTest.ch
     service: http://myTest:6001
     access:
      required: true
      teamName: group.ch
      audTag:
        - XXXXXXXXXXXX

Honestly, i'm lost, i don't know what is wrong, i don't what i should set up.
The current error that come out from the console is:
app-DOGVOsY_.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'wss://textAPP:6001/app/123456?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
